# I'm always receiving the same item

Tags: android, gridview, tags, baseadapter

Each item created is an object of type Product which have a name, price and quantity. It happens that when I'm trying to receive in a gridview each item's position I always get the first item of the view. I watched several other posts before posting my problem and it seems like I'm doing everything right in order how to use the tags.

I have

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
ViewHolder holder = null;
    if (convertView == null || (convertView.getTag() == null)) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_values, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.productName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewList1);
        holder.productQuantity = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.EditTextList2);
        holder.productPrice = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewList3);
        holder.removeProduct = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.removeProduct);
    }
    else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    convertView.setTag(holder);
    holder.productName.setText(products.get(position).getProductName());
    holder.productQuantity.setText(String.valueOf(products.get(position).getProductQuantity()) + " Un.");
    holder.productPrice.setText(String.valueOf(products.get(position).getProductPrice())+ " €");
    holder.removeProduct.setTag(new Integer(position));

    return convertView;
}
```

and

```
 public void removeProduct(View v) {

    ImageButton removeProduct = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.removeProduct);
    Integer position = (Integer) removeProduct.getTag();

    Product p1 = (Product) adapter.getItem(position);

    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this,"You want to remove the item: "+ position +" with the product name: "+ p1.getProductName() + " , quantity: "+ p1.getProductQuantity()
            + " , price: " + p1.getProductPrice(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG); toast.show();
}
```

When i run the emulator now matter what item i click i get always this result:

[image]

If you need to see any more code just tell me and i'll post it. Thank you in advance guys.

Comment: Can you try this: Integer position = (Integer) v.getTag();

Comment: it works but i don't get it, can u explain it? ... thanks by the way

Comment: You are getting the tag always from the same object when you do the findViewById, is for that you have to get the tag from the parameter "v"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your  `removeProduct()` to -

```
public void removeProduct(View v) {    
    Integer position = (Integer) v.getTag();

    Product p1 = (Product) adapter.getItem(position);

    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this,"You want to remove the item: "+ position +" with the product name: "+ p1.getProductName() + " , quantity: "+ p1.getProductQuantity()
            + " , price: " + p1.getProductPrice(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG); toast.show();
}
```

The reason is because you are again initializing your view by

```
  ImageButton removeProduct = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.removeProduct)
```

and this is no longer the same view which you clicked.
Your clicked view is the parameter passed in `removeProduct()`

Comment: then why am i receiving the tag of the removeProduct and not of the convertView object?

Comment: "View v" is the same convertView object.